# Livewire v3 nested component error: Dispatch does not exist in nested component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have to components:
Quest/Edit - parent
Quest/Sheep - nested/child

I want to update the `sheep` property of the parent component from child. I was going to use events for that but I am getting the following error, I couldn't find any discussion on this topic. Can any one direct me to the solution?

I am getting the following error:
`Method App\Http\Livewire\Quest\Sheep::dispatch does not exist.`

Parent component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Quest;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
class Edit extends Component
{
    public $quest;
    public $sheep = [];
    ...
    public function updated($property)
    {
        $properties = explode('.', $property);
        $property   = $properties[0];
        if ($property == 'sheep') {
            dd($this->sheep);
        }
        if (isset($this->quest->{$property})) {
            $this->quest->{$property} = $this->{$property};
            $this->quest->save();
        }
    }

    #[On('property-updated')]
    public function updatedProperty($property, $value)
    {
        $this->{$property} = $value;
        $this->updated($property);
    }
...
```

Edit.blade.php

```
<div x-cloak x-show="tab === 'sheep'" class="space-y-4">
    <livewire:quest.sheep :sheep="$sheep" />
</div>
```

Child component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Quest;

use App\Models\MlpSheepWeight;
use Livewire\Component;

class Sheep extends Component
{
    public $sheep = [];
    public function mount($sheep)
    {
        $this->sheep = $sheep;
        $this->sheepWeights   = MlpSheepWeight::data();
    }

    public function updated($property)
    {
        $properties = explode('.', $property);
        $property   = $properties[0];
        if ($property == 'sheep') {
            $this->dispatch('property-updated', property: 'sheep', value: $this->sheep)->to(Edit::class);
        }
    }
...
```

I searched the documentation, for me I am writing the exact code stated on the documentation but it is giving me error.

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Note that you may want to avoid the *dispatch()* when calling a parent action: take a look [here](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events) at the section *"You might not need events"*